# How to wait for setIcon() method to execute before resuming the code?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, graphics2d, paintcomponent

I have a code that goes like this:

```
jLabel.setIcon(map);
Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) jLabel.getGraphics();
g.drawPolygon(xpoints,ypoints,vpolygonpointsarray.length);
```

But what happens is that the polygon is drawn first before the labels icon is updated. I suspect setting an icon creates a new thread. I would like to wait until the icon is set before the rest of the code is executed. How would I do that?

Comment: Setting the icon most definitely does NOT create a new thread. A repaint event is scheduled for later, however, which is likely causing your problems. Real the tutorial link @vizier added below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do your custom painting code in an overridden paint method (`paint()`, `paintComponents()` etc.). Check here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step2.html

Comment: In this case the poblem is not related with waiting for a method to end. You are in a single threaded part of the  code. The problem is this: you paint on component graphics but when swing tries to repaint the component, it calls the update/paint methods which simply paints over what you have done. For this reason, we override paint method and make sure we do custom painting everytime swing repaint the component.